# Spliting a Dynamic string in python

Tags: python

Is it posible to get Some key values from this string

"Best case"

```
A = '<main=NewStuff stuff named This_is_dynamic/Dynamic_Meta_Info with ID 12345 in 88981>'
```

```py
def get_important_values(A):
    
    newlist = []
    
    test = A.split(" ")
    print (test)
    
    count = 4
    while True:
        if count == 100:
            print ("COunt Breakout")
            break
        
        if test[count] == "with":
            print (count)
            if count != 4:
                print (type(test[5]))
                test[3:count-1] = [''.join(map(str, test[3:count-1]))]
                    
            else:
                pass # do nothing
            break
        else:
            pass
            
        count +=1
        
    print (test)
    
    KeyValue1 = test[0]
    KeyValue2 = test[3]
    KeyValue3 = test[6]
    keyValue4 = test[9]
    return KeyValue1, KeyValue2, KeyValue3, KeyValue4


A = '<main=NewStuff stuff named This_is_dynamic/Dynamic_Meta_Info with ID 12345 in 88981>'

get_important_values(A)
```

But If I tried this as the string insted I Have a few issues

```
A = '<main=NewStuff stuff named This is dyn a mi  c/Dynamic_Meta_Info with ID 12345 in 88981>'
```

1. I want index 3 to be like this `"This is dyn a mi  c/Dynamic_Meta_Info"` but what i get is this `"Thisisdynami"` I loose all the spaces and I also don't get the whole thing
2. is there a better way to do this

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamic mixed"? the general verbiage of this question is difficult to parse.

Comment: I updated the question it is more understandable thanks

Comment: Verbs and interpunction aren't things you can just liberally sprinkle over a text in the hopes of making it readable. Also, please format your code by indenting or using triple backticks. The "WorseCase" [sic] and "Best case" are identical, what do you mean there? Your split apparently works - are you asking about `"/".join(result)`? What do you mean by "3 is unpredictable"? Please provide some examples of strings that work and ones that don't - less chat, more code.

Comment: WHoa thnks that help I think I finally nailed the question it's more understandable now and shorter. thank you in advance

Comment: something like `A.replace("This is dynamic/name it_again", "This_is_dynamic/name_it_again")` should work for the worst case, shouldn't it?

Comment: Am not trying to edit It I don't even know what is going to be there.

Comment: Am not trying to edit It I don't even know what is going to be there. What am trying to do is 1. get the string 2. Split it so I can add the needed information into a variable that will be use for refrenceing later

Comment: it seems some elements you could get usin negative index `Adresss = ListObject[-1]` `Identity  = ListObject[-3]` and maybe rest you could get using range `[3:-6]`. But if this not work then maybe you will need `regex` to get all between `named` and `with`

Comment: Thanks I tried that and also updated my question maybe using regex would be the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def get_important_values(A : str):


    # first I used inverted stings to the first and and last value

    test = A.split(" ")

    if test[4] != "with":
        ss = re.search(r'stuff named (.*?) with ID',A).group(1)
    else:
        ss = test[3]

    Value1 = test[0]
    Value 2 = ss.rsplit("/", 1)
    Value 3 = ElementName_Type[0]
    Value Address = test[-1]
    return Value1, Value 2


A = '<main=NewStuff stuff named This_is_dynamic/Dynamic_Meta_Info with ID 12345 in 88981>'

get_important_values(A)
```